# what is wrong in this it is not inserting

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am getting this error like 
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'service_type' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `services` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (2019-09-11 04:36:26, 2019-09-11 04:36:26))

ServiceController

```
public function store(Request $request, Service $service)
    {
    //        
       $service->service_type = $request->service_type;
       $service->service_name = $request->service_name;
       $service->service_price = $request->service_price;

       $service->create();
       return redirect()->route('service.show');

    }
```

service table

```
public function up()
    {
       Schema::create('services', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->bigIncrements('service_id');
       $table->string('service_type');
       $table->string('service_name');
       $table->string('service_price');            
       $table->timestamps();
     });
    }
```

table 
    service_id  service_type    service_name    service_price   created_at  updated_at

service blade

```
<div class="input-w">
  <label class="label-style">Service Type:</label>
  <span><select id="service_type" name="service_type"  class="form-control" required >
  <option></option>
  <option type="brillare">Brillare</option>
  <option type="hair">Hair</option>
  </select></span>
  </div>
  <div class="input-w">
  <label name="service_name">Service Name:</label>
  <span><input id="service_name" name="service_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Service Name" required ></span>
  </div>

  <div class="input-w">
  <label name="service_price">Service Price:</label>
  <span><input type="number" id="service_price" name="service_price" class="form-control" required placeholder="0000.00"></span>
  </div>                       

  <div align="center" class="button_style">
  <p style="margin:15px -40px 20px 182px"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_service" value="Submit" class="btn btn-outline-success"></p>

  </div>
```

Comment: I don't see how your code is even generating that insert statement, but the error is obvious and is just telling you that the `service_type` column was given no value, and there is no default value for that column.

Comment: i am new to this laravel please tell me how to give

Comment: I am also new to Laravel.  Start with the `INSERT` statement from the error message, and try to understand why it is wrong.  Then, return to your PHP code and see if you can fix that too.

Comment: Thanks it worked Thank you very much it inserted